# C-l in iimage-mode

Tags: key-bindings, image-mode

`iimage-mode` rebinds `C-l` to `iimage-recenter` instead of the usual `recenter-top-bottom`.

1. What is the logic behind this remapping? If it's there, I'm guessing it must be somehow useful, despite that the original mapping to recenter is normally so sacred to emacs users.
2. How do I disable the new mapping and return to the old one? The attempt below is not good.

```el
 (add-hook 'iimage-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (global-unset-key "\C-l")
            ))
```

(As an aside, stackexchange's markdown for code blocks used to handle elisp just fine, until recently.)

Answer (score 1):

About your first question:

> What is the logic behind this remapping? If it's there, I'm guessing it must be somehow useful, despite that the original mapping to recenter is normally so sacred to emacs users.

You should have a look at the description of `iimage-recenter`:

> Re-draw images and recenter.

The "re-draw images" part is not covered by `recenter-top-bottom`. If you look at the code you see that this function removes essentially the `'display 'image` property and adds it again afterwards. That destroys the cache for the image and reads it anew from the file. I think

`(clear-image-cache (expand-file-name "filename"))`

instead would also do the trick.

About your second question:

> How do I disable the new mapping and return to the old one? The attempt below is not good.

`iimage-mode` uses the minor-mode map `iimage-mode-map`. You can just unset the key there:

```el
(define-key iimage-mode-map "\C-l" nil)
```

The variable `iimage-mode-map` is defined by `defvar` in `iimage.el`.
If you already `require` `iimage` in your initialization put the above line **behind** that `require`-statement.
If `iimage` is loaded automatically by some other package put the following line in your initialization files:

```el
(eval-after-load "iimage" '(define-key iimage-mode-map "\C-l" nil))
```

Comment: iimage-mode is invaluable, but it's puzzling that it's so heavy handed in terms of expectation of usage. I may sometimes start from the images and write the text afterwards, but quite often what works for me is to write the text first and produce the images later. In that case I don't want iimage-mode to protest that the images are not ready.

Comment: Something's not right: `Symbol's value as variable is void: iimage-mode-map`. Is it not necessary to wrap this line in a hook? Otherwise it fails unless iimage-mode has already loaded.

Comment: @Calaf See my edit at the end of the answer.